# Geojson/ turf : merge multiple polygons to one polygon keeping hole

Tags: leaflet, polygon, geojson, turfjs

So I want to merge adjacent polygons in javascript this is what I actually have with my code:

[image: map]

I want to remove inside stroke but keep border stroke.

So I want to go from this:

[image: map2]

To this:

[image: map3]

I want to keep the hole for Paris - I can defined which polygons have to be grouped but I cannot merge them with this code:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [46.52863469527167, 2.43896484375],
    zoom: 6,
    maxZoom: 18,
    minZoom: 7
});
$http.get("france.json").then(function (response) {
    $scope.communeFr = response.data.features
    $http.get(apiult).then(function (response) {
        $scope.showCommune = response.data.Liste
        $scope.communeFr.map(x => {
            x.show = false
            for (let i = 0; i < $scope.showCommune .length; i++) {
                if (x.properties.insee == $scope.showCommune[i].insee) {
                    x.show = true
                    return
                }
            }                
        })
        L.geoJson($scope.communeFr, {
            filter: function (feature, latlng) {
                return feature.show 
            }
        }).addTo(map);
    });
    
});
```

UPDATE - I tried with `turf.union` but the output is not right:

[image: map4]

This is my code

```
var GroupPolygons = [];    
$scope.communeFr.map(x => {
    x.show = false
    for (let i = 0; i < $scope.showCommune .length; i++) {
        if (x.properties.insee == $scope.showCommune[i].insee) {
            GroupPolygons.push(x)
        }
    }                
})
var union = turf.union(...GroupPolygons)
L.geoJson(union).addTo(map)
```

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd images don't seem to tie to the 1st ?

Comment: If you want to merge polygons use [@turf/union](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/tree/master/packages/turf-union)

Comment: @RobinMackenzie it's not the same image it's just to show u what I want exactly

Comment: @GrzegorzT. I already try to use turf.union, I guess I do something wrong I will show u my code and what I get

Comment: I have created a generic tool to merge geojson features: https://github.com/abdurrahmanyildiz/geojson-feature-merger

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There seems to be an ambiguity in the turf docs concerning `union` regarding the number of polygons that can be passed as arguments. See [here](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/pull/1285) and [here](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/pull/1285). Looks like it has to be two at a time - so this will work:

```
// feature ids to remove e.g. central Paris
var removeIds = [868, 869, 870, 871, 872, 873, 874, 875, 876, 877, 878, 879, 880, 881, 882, 883, 884, 885, 886, 887];

// filter features to remove central Paris
var hole = fc.features.filter(f => !removeIds.includes(f.properties.ID_APUR))

// do the union over each feature
var union = hole[0];
for (let i=1; i<hole.length; i++) {
  union = turf.union(union, hole[i]);
}
```

I selected a bunch of central Paris to remove and then from the remaining features I start with feature 0 and then `turf.join` all the other features (from index 1 onward) to this one. Seems inefficient but works...

Small gotcha here:

```
// new Feature collection with unioned features
var fc2 = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [union] // note features has to be an array
}
```

Remember to pass a FeatureCollection to `L.geoJson` and that the `features` property needs to be an array - even though in this case it contains a single feature of the merged areas.

Working example:

```js
// center map on Paris
var map = L.map('mapid', {
    center: [48.856, 2.352],
    zoom: 9,
    maxZoom: 18,
    minZoom: 1
});

// add tiles
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/robinmackenzie/937e5bd42a0412c21281f69b8f0c8614/raw/fbed7c2783366463a250e4bb0ebcf3c5f6d54dfe/greaterParis.geo.json";

// get greater Paris definition
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(fc => { 

    // feature ids to remove e.g. central Paris
    var removeIds = [868, 869, 870, 871, 872, 873, 874, 875, 876, 877, 878, 879, 880, 881, 882, 883, 884, 885, 886, 887];

    // filter features to remove central Paris
    var hole = fc.features.filter(f => !removeIds.includes(f.properties.ID_APUR))

    // do the union over each feature
    var union = hole[0];
    for (let i=1; i<hole.length; i++) {
      union = turf.union(union, hole[i]);
    }

    // new Feature collection with unioned features
    var fc2 = {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [union] // note features has to be an array
    }

    // add to map
    L.geoJson(fc2).addTo(map);
  
  });
```

```css
#mapid { height: 200px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@turf/turf@6.3.0/turf.min.js'></script>
<div id="mapid"></div>
```

Comment: U ARE MY HERO thank you sooooooooooo much

Comment: @user10863293 no worries, feel free to upvote if the solution helped you.

Comment: Thank you Robin. If smb needs to merge features, I have created a generic tool to merge geojson features: https://github.com/abdurrahmanyildiz/geojson-feature-merger